# Can't find certain words in Lucene.NET search

Tags: html, lucene.net

I'm loading 500+ html documents into an index and most searches work properly. However, some of them don't...such as "italic" or "bold".

```
public static void LoadTopics(string informPath)
{
    var path = new DirectoryInfo(Path.Combine(new FileInfo(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory).Directory.FullName, "LuceneIndex"));
    if (!path.Exists)
    {
        path.Create();
        path.Refresh();
    }

    ISet<string> emptySet = new SortedSet<string>();

    Analyzer analyzer = new StandardAnalyzer(Lucene.Net.Util.Version.LUCENE_30, emptySet);

    FSDirectory directory = new SimpleFSDirectory(path);
    IndexWriter iwriter = new IndexWriter(directory, analyzer, new IndexWriter.MaxFieldLength(140));

    // get list of I7 html documentation files
    List<Inform7Topic> topics = new List<Inform7Topic>();
    string[] docFiles = System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(informPath + @"\Documentation\", "doc*.html", SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly);
    string[] rdocFiles = System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(informPath + @"\Documentation\", "rdoc*.html", SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly);

    List<string> docs = new List<string>();
    docs.AddRange(docFiles);
    docs.AddRange(rdocFiles);

    foreach (string topic in docs)
    {
        string html = File.ReadAllText(topic);

        HtmlDocument hdoc = new HtmlDocument();
        hdoc.LoadHtml(html);

        string title = hdoc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//title").InnerText;

        int p1 = title.IndexOf(".");
        int p2 = title.IndexOf(".", p1 + 1);
        string chapter = title.Substring(0, p1);
        string section = title.Substring(p1 + 1, p2 - p1 - 1);

        if (!IsIndexedTopic(chapter, section))
        {
            Document doc = new Document();
            doc.Add(new Field("chapter", chapter, Field.Store.YES, Field.Index.ANALYZED));
            doc.Add(new Field("section", section, Field.Store.YES, Field.Index.ANALYZED));
            doc.Add(new Field("title", title, Field.Store.YES, Field.Index.ANALYZED));
            doc.Add(new Field("contents", html, Field.Store.YES, Field.Index.ANALYZED));
            doc.Add(new Field("filepath", topic, Field.Store.YES, Field.Index.ANALYZED));
            iwriter.AddDocument(doc);
        }
    }

    iwriter.Commit();
    iwriter.Dispose();
}

    public static List<Inform7Topic> SearchTopics(string searchTerm)
    {
        var path = new DirectoryInfo(Path.Combine(new FileInfo(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory).Directory.FullName, "LuceneIndex"));
        if (!path.Exists)
        {
            path.Create();
            path.Refresh();
        }

        ISet<string> emptySet = new SortedSet<string>();
        FSDirectory directory = new SimpleFSDirectory(path);
        Analyzer analyzer = new StandardAnalyzer(Lucene.Net.Util.Version.LUCENE_30, emptySet);

        // Now search the index:
        IndexReader ireader = DirectoryReader.Open(directory, true);
        IndexSearcher isearcher = new IndexSearcher(ireader);


        QueryParser parser = new QueryParser(Lucene.Net.Util.Version.LUCENE_30, "contents", analyzer);
        Query query = parser.Parse(searchTerm);
        ScoreDoc[] hits = isearcher.Search(query, null, 1000).ScoreDocs;
        // Iterate through the results:
        List<Inform7Topic> viewModel = new List<Inform7Topic>();
        for (int i = 0; i < hits.Length; i++)
        {
            Document hitDoc = isearcher.Doc(hits[i].Doc);

            Inform7Topic topic = new Inform7Topic();
            string chapter = hitDoc.GetField("chapter").StringValue;
            string section = hitDoc.GetField("section").StringValue;
            string title = hitDoc.GetField("title").StringValue;
            string filePath = hitDoc.GetField("filepath").StringValue;
            string contents = hitDoc.GetField("contents").StringValue;

            topic.Chapter = chapter;
            topic.Section = section;
            topic.Title = title;
            topic.FilePath = filePath;
            topic.Score = hits[i].Score;

            viewModel.Add(topic);
        }
        ireader.Dispose();
        analyzer.Dispose();
        directory.Dispose();

        return viewModel;
    }
```

As you can see, I've even tried an empty stop word list. I can't get any hits on "italic" and that word is in 44 html files. Now in some cases, the word is in a javascript string, but Lucene should see the whole document as just a string of text, right?

What am I missing?

Comment: So I added a simple test with "this is the roman bold italic test" and that returns results...so it's not the words. It must be the way Lucene is compiling the document index from those documents. Still investigating.

Comment: Does StandardAnalyzer remove HTML?

Comment: I pulled InnerText out of the document and stripped all of the special characters out and added that to each document...still no hits. There are five instances of the word "italic" in one document so I know it should work. Weird. Something is telling Lucene to stop parsing. I want to know what it is.

Comment: This is a document that fails on search term "italic". http://pastebin.com/ywH1Tr81

Comment: Can you show your searcher code?